# I need to combine below 2 codes to 1 code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having a website and recently I have signed up for a website monetization program.

My website is a script that was downloaded from a website called faucet pay.

In my website admin panel, I can put my ad codes but I have no idea about how to combine those codes and which part to be replaced.

Below mentioned code was provided by the monetization provider to insert it on the website as a display ad.

```
<script> async="async" data-cfasync="false" src="//upgulpinon.com/1?z=4278445"></script>
```

but on my website ad slot code goes as below,

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Add a real banner here.');"><img src="https://placehold.it/468x60"></a>
```

How should I edit and combine this code as a one code to display the ad provided by the monetization provider

Please help me out.